# Correct SQL Query returning the wrong result in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

```
    // check if user exists
        $query = "SELECT playerID FROM PLAYERS where steamid = ? LIMIT 1";
            if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
                echo "Steamid: $in_steamID...<br />";
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $in_steamID);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $out_playerID);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                    $in_playerID = $out_playerID;
                }
            }
            echo ("Player ID: $in_playerID  <br />");
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is as follows:

1. Parse some data from some log files and store them in variables ->> no problems here
2. Send this data through queries to my database

The problem is the query I've included in the codetags, it should do the following:

1. Check the database to see if the current SteamID has a playerID in the database - if it does return its playerID.

The problem is, the query  always seems to return a 1 regardless of what it should actually return, even if there are no rows returned at all. I can't figure out why.

I have ran this SQL statement outside of my PHP script and it works perfectly...

I have desk checked the variables multiple times and have even printed them during the scripts runtime to ensure they contain the correct values... and they are! What should I do now?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if only query one is failing pleas only post it, we don't need or want to see all the code that does not relate to the question

Comment: Would you like me to remove the other code? I left it there for context sake. My apologies.

Comment: @Dagon I have removed the irrelevant code and restructured my question if you wanted to have a look now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable $in_playerID is never given a value when rows aren't returned. By default, $in_playerID seemed to contain 1. I can only assume this must be the contents of some random memory address.

To fix this, I simply declared $in_playerID above the query.

`$in_playerID = 0;`